# two templates never get executed. What am I missing here?

Tags: xml, xslt

I have this (part of an) XML file, named a.opf:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <package xmlns="http://www.idpf.org/2007/opf" version="3.0" xml:lang="nl" unique-identifier="isbn-id" prefix="cc: http://creativecommons.org/ns# rendition: http://www.idpf.org/vocab/rendition/# ibooks: http://vocabulary.itunes.apple.com/rdf/ibooks/vocabulary-extensions-1.0/">
   <metadata xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/">
    <dc:title id="title">good book</dc:title>
    <meta refines="#title" property="title-type">main</meta>
    <meta property="ibooks:version">1.0.411</meta>
    <dc:language>nl</dc:language>
    <meta property="dcterms:modified">2014-05-24T21:58:45Z</meta>
    <dc:publisher>none</dc:publisher>
   </metadata>
</package>
```

which I transform with this stylesheet:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="meta[@property='ibooks:version']">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:analyze-string select="." regex="([0-9]*\.[0-9]*\.)([0-9]*)">
            <xsl:matching-substring>
                <xsl:value-of select="regex-group(1)"/>
                <xsl:value-of select="number(regex-group(2)) + 1"/>
            </xsl:matching-substring>
            <xsl:non-matching-substring>
                <xsl:text>1.0.0</xsl:text>
            </xsl:non-matching-substring>
        </xsl:analyze-string>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="meta[@property='dcterms:modified']">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:value-of select="current-dateTime()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Why are the two meta templates never executed?
The file a.opf just gets copied.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing namespace declarations in your XSLT.

In your XML you start off with this namespace declaration....

```
<package xmlns="http://www.idpf.org/2007/opf"
```

This means the **package** element, and any child elements (with the exceptions of ones already prefixed with **dc:**) belong to that namespace.

However, in your XSLT, where you do this...

```
<xsl:template match="meta[...]">
```

It is trying to match **meta** elements in NO namespace, which is not the same as the **meta** element in your XML which are in namespaces.

In XSLT 1.0, you would have to add a declaration of the namespace in the XSLT along with a prefix...

```
<xsl:stylesheet ...
     xmlns:opf="http://www.idpf.org/2007/opf"
```

Then you would use this prefix in any xpath expression...

```
<xsl:template match="opf:meta[@property='dcterms:modified']">
```

However, you are using XSLT 2.0, so you can just add this to your **xsl:stylesheet** element

```
<xsl:stylesheet ...
     xpath-default-namespace="http://www.idpf.org/2007/opf"
```

This means any elements in xpath expressions, such as the template match, that don't have a prefix, will be assumed to belong to the default namespace.

Try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
      xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions"
      xpath-default-namespace="http://www.idpf.org/2007/opf">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="meta[@property='ibooks:version']">uuu
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:analyze-string select="." regex="([0-9]*\.[0-9]*\.)([0-9]*)">
            <xsl:matching-substring>
                <xsl:value-of select="regex-group(1)"/>
                <xsl:value-of select="number(regex-group(2)) + 1"/>
            </xsl:matching-substring>
            <xsl:non-matching-substring>
                <xsl:text>1.0.0</xsl:text>
            </xsl:non-matching-substring>
        </xsl:analyze-string>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="meta[@property='dcterms:modified']">4444
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:value-of select="current-dateTime()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```